# How to do analysis on subsets of a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, subset

I'm working with a dataset that shows flights taken by different people. Each line lists a flight segment and every couple of lines makes up an itinerary. So a simplified example of what the data looks like is:

```
Passenger_1   First_Airport    Second_Airport    Distance from 1-2
Passenger_1   Second_Airport   Third_Airport     Distance from 2-3
Passenger_2   First_Airport    Second_Airport    Distance from 1-2
....
```

(So here Passenger_1 traveled from the First Airport to the Third stopping over in the Second, while Passenger_2 flew non-stop from First to Second)

What I want to do is pull out each itinerary (all the rows that have the same passenger in the first column), pull out the data I need and then put it all into a new file, where each line now is an itinerary rather than a flight segment. Ideally it would look something like:

```
Passenger   Origin          Destination     Distance Travelled
Passenger_1 First_Airport   Third_Airport   Distance from 1-2+Distance from 2-3
Passenger_2 First_Airport   Second_Airport  Distance from 1-2
....
```

The way I managed to find to do this was:

```
d = []
for group in data.groupby(data.MKT_ID):
    x=group[1]

    (Do all the analysis I want to do on x)

    d.append({'Var_1': Var1(x), 
    'Var_2': Var_2(x),})

Output=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

This works fine but runs very slowly, about 15min to do one dataset. The datasets are a bit over 1GB in .csv format, each containing something like 600,000 itineraries and about 1,000,000 segments. I have something like 40 of these datasets to work with, so would like to be able to do this munging faster if possible.

Is there a faster way to do this? I don't have much coding experience so not too sure how long something like this should take, but it seems rather long to me. Also it seems like I'm using .groupby differently than most uses I've found while searching, is there a better way to pull out subsets and run analysis on them like this?

Edit:
The (Do all the analysis I want to do on x) Section is:

```
x=group[1].reset_index(drop=True)
x=x.sort_values(['SEQ_NUM'], ascending=1)
destIndex = x.shape[0]-1
MKT_ID = x.MKT_ID[0]
ITIN_ID = x.ITIN_ID[0]
ORIGIN = x.ORIGIN[0]
DEST = x.DEST[destIndex]
ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID = x.ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID[0]
ORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID = x.ORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID[0]
DEST_AIRPORT_ID = x.DEST_AIRPORT_ID[destIndex]
DEST_CITY_MARKET_ID = x.DEST_CITY_MARKET_ID[destIndex]
CARRIER = x.TICKET_CARRIER[0] 
DISTANCE = sum(x.DISTANCE)
PASSENGERS = x.PASSENGERS[0]
TRANSFERS = destIndex

ROUTE = sorted([ORIGIN,DEST])
ROUTE = ROUTE[0] + '-' + ROUTE[1]

STOPS=''
for XXX in x.ORIGIN[1:]:
    STOPS = STOPS+'"'+XXX+'"'

if len(set(x.TICKET_CARRIER)) == 1:
    INTERLINE = 0
else:    
    INTERLINE = 1

if (min(x.SEQ_NUM) == 1)&(max(x.SEQ_NUM) == x.COUPONS[0]):
    ONEWAY = 1
else:
    ONEWAY = 0

d.append({'MKT_ID': MKT_ID, 
    'ITIN_ID': ITIN_ID, 
    'ORIGIN': ORIGIN,
    'DEST': DEST,
    'ORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID': ORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID,
    'DEST_CITY_MARKET_ID': DEST_CITY_MARKET_ID,
    'CARRIER': CARRIER,
    'DISTANCE': DISTANCE,
    'PASSENGERS': PASSENGERS,
    'TRANSFERS': TRANSFERS,
    'STOPS': STOPS,
    'ROUTE': ROUTE,
    'ONEWAY': ONEWAY,
    'INTERLINE': INTERLINE     })
```

Edit: The datafile I am working with can be found here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9sRZp8Q6aVdUVhKQW9DaWlYR0k

Comment: You can pass in an analysis function into the `apply` method of `data.groupby('MKT_ID')`. That should be faster than looping through each group.

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the section `(Do all the analysis I want to do on x)`.

Comment: I've added that section in now. What do you mean by 'analysis function'? (a quick google didn't find anything). Do you mean things like summary stats over the group like 'sum', 'max', &c. If so then there are a couple of things in there I couldn't do (or at least am not sure how) with those (e.g. finding the origin airport)

Comment: If you want real help on this, you should include the data that you're processing (or at least a subest). Otherwise (or additionally), I recommend using `ipython` and the `%lprun`  profiler to figure out where your bottleneck is.

Comment: There's plenty that could be simplified, for sure, but the only bottleneck I can see without running the code is the call to `sort_values`. You could do the same with `min` of `SEQ_NUM`.

Comment: I've put the dataset I'm using in my Google Drive and added a link (is there a better way to do this?)

Comment: Getting rid of the sort lowers the runtime by about 20%. So I'll fix that up, but it's still going to take a while. Currently looking at %lprun (Also ipython is already used when I'm in Jupyter right?)